# Wordpress: media library grid mode infinite loading

Tags: wordpress

So this problem is very strange because for me doesn't work Wordpress media library in Wordpress admin menu only grid mode, its very strange problem because this problem occurs ONLY on 1 account/ That would be same account that yesterday i was trying upload bunch of pictures to media library and it gave error:

> Try again later...

Since that i have tried many things but besides logging with other account nothing helped.

1. Tried reninstall wordpress via wordpress admin panel
2. Tried disabling all plugins, changed theme to default wordpress
3. Tried inspect elemet for JS errors nothing there except

> upload.php?mode=grid:46 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi'
> means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not
> correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression:
> print, not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
> (min-resolution: 120dpi)

4. Tried include in theme functions bunch of codes that i found on internet didn't helped.(i don't have them now since nothing helped and i didn't saved them sorry...)
5. Tried flushing cache, proxy, different computers, different operating systems(max,windows), tablet nothing still on that particular account media grid view doesn't work

   View that 'm seeing is this:
   [image]

I don't understand whats wrong, why on 1 particular account it doesn't work i even tried flushing Wordpress cache but it doesn't work after i received that error which i showed above. Did somebody know how can i solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Got exactly the same problem and some ajax error on revolution slider too, and after searching for long time i resolved my problem.

It was just an HTML comment in functions.php on child theme, after remove it, everything work perfectly for me.

Same problem with space in function.php don't cut your code with space between php tag

Comment: I had a similar error: there was a space after the `?>` tag. Removing the space solved the issue.

Comment: @AndrewCox Thanks, I had spaces as well. Solved!

Answer (score 3):

this type problem is create by **functions.php** file , remove the code of you added in **functions.php** and than see it work proper.

standerd code write in functions.php file

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was an error in the backend. You should check your network tab in developer tools and find admin-ajax.php. Even if it returns HTTP 200, it shows an error in the response body.

From the information provided, you can work on which plugin, theme, or whatever file causes the error.

[image: network tab in developer console]

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with the user and seeing that you have tried almost all, you can try deleting the user and creating it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error. I could not search for plugins, get the list of my uploads, everywhere where an ajax function was triggered, I needed to reload the page to see the results.

clean your functions.php and see if it works now. if yes, clean up your functions.php search for spaces or not set closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simple – I just had accidentally added a closing php tag in my functions.php `(?>)`.
After I removed it the problem was solved.